# Apache reverse proxy - URL without / is refused

Tags: apache-http-server, proxy, reverse-proxy

I use reverse proxy to show backend server content for a subdomain.
The subdomain.mydomain.com (server A) should display content of server with IP 123.123.123.123 port 1111 (server B).

Virtual host of subdomain.mydomain.com (server A):

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName subdomain.mydomain.com

SSLEngine on
SecAuditEngine On
RewriteEngine On
SSLProxyEngine on
ProxyPreserveHost On
LogLevel warn

<Directory />
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Location />
    ProxyPass https://123.123.123.123:1111
    ProxyPassReverse https://123.123.123.123:1111
</Location>

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

SSLProtocol             all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLHonorCipherOrder     on
SSLVerifyClient none
SSLVerifyDepth 1

SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/cert.site/chain_wildcard_site_combined.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/cert.site/key_wildcard_site.key
 
SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

</VirtualHost>                                  
</IfModule>
```

Virtual host of 123.123.123.123:1111 (server B):

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost 123.123.123.123:1111>
        DocumentRoot /srv/www/site/htdocs

SSLEngine on
RewriteEngine On
SSLProxyEngine on
ProxyPreserveHost On
LogLevel warn

<Location "/">
   Require ip 222.222.222.222
</Location>

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>

<Directory /srv/www/site/htdocs>
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

ErrorLog /srv/www/site/log/error.log
CustomLog /srv/www/site/log/access.log combined
CustomLog /srv/www/site/log/ssl_request_log \
            "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

SSLProtocol             all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLHonorCipherOrder     on
SSLVerifyClient none
SSLVerifyDepth 1

SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/cert.site/chain_wildcard_site_combined.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/cert.site/key_wildcard_site.key

        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>

    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

If I load URL:
https://subdomain.mydomain.com/dir/

it loads successfully.

If I load URL (without trailing slash):
https://subdomain.mydomain.com/dir

it results error page: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

**EDIT1:**

I execute command:

```
curl -IL https://subdomain.mydomain.com/dir
```

and I get this result:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Mon, 23 Aug 2021 13:45:13 GMT
Server: Apache
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains
Location: https://subdomain.mydomain.com:1111/dir/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

curl: (7) Failed to connect to subdomain.mydomain.com port 1111: Connection refused
```

**EDIT2:**

I added trailing slash

```
<Location />
    ProxyPass https://123.123.123.123:1111/
    ProxyPassReverse https://123.123.123.123:1111/
</Location>
```

But I still get the **Connection refused** error.

Any idea why is it resulting error, when trailing slash is missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to add a forward-slash at the end of the `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` directives, like this: `ProxyPass https://123.123.123.123:1111/`.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/334323/nginx-proxypath-https-redirect-fails-without-trailing-slash ?

Comment: Cross posting is not recommended https://superuser.com/questions/1670420/apache-reverse-proxy-url-without-is-refused , at least without cross linking.

Comment: @harrymc - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/665846/apache-reverse-proxy-url-without-is-refused#comment1253003_665846

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio: The OP put up his bounty here, not in SO. The most you can advice is to delete his post on SO. Funnily, he got there a similar comment to mine, so maybe this is worth an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Although it's really difficult to correlate `subdomain.domain.com`, `123.123.123.123`, and `222.222.222.222`, two issues jump out at me. Here's my take on what I think you're telling us.

1. ProxyPass directives must *always* have a trailing slash:

   ```
    <Location />
        ProxyPass https://123.123.123.123:1111/
        ProxyPassReverse https://123.123.123.123:1111/
    </Location>
   ```

   You corrected this in an edit/update but there are no new testing results to show the effect of the fix.
2. You're proxying to the host `123.123.123.123`, and the `VirtualHost` directive expects this, but there's no `ServerName` entry to match the original servername as required by `ProxyPreserveHost`.

   - Remove `ProxyPreserveHost` from Server B
   - Add `ServerName` to Server B to match the IP address defined in Server A's `ProxyPass` URI

Don't forget to look carefully at the access and error logs generated by Server A and Server B; they exist for good reason.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed advices! I will go through your advices one by one, tomorrow.

Comment: @klor did this work for you? If so please consider accepting the answer with the tick mark alongside the answer so that I can get the bonus you've offered